# Flutter - Time.now() on TextFormField

Tags: flutter, timepicker

I add one time picker in Flutter. Like this...

```
Future<Null> dataloggerHour(
      BuildContext context, TextEditingController controller) async {
    final TimeOfDay picked =
        await showTimePicker(context: context, initialTime: time);
    if (picked != null && picked != TimeOfDay.now()) {
      picked.format(context);
      setState(() {
        var transform = picked.format(context).split(" ");
        controller.text = transform[0];
      });
    }
  }
```

I need to add this date on a input field. The problem is when i convert this date to string, delete the zeros on the left.

Example data is: 08:00, when parse returns 80:0.

How can i keep this zeros?

Comment: how did you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

In the [official documentation](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/TimeOfDay/toString.html) they override the toString method to add 0s automatically. You need to use the .toString() method.

```
@override
String toString() {
  String _addLeadingZeroIfNeeded(int value) {
    if (value < 10)
      return '0$value';
    return value.toString();
  }

  final String hourLabel = _addLeadingZeroIfNeeded(hour);
  final String minuteLabel = _addLeadingZeroIfNeeded(minute);

  return '$TimeOfDay($hourLabel:$minuteLabel)';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retain leading zeros you can use `padLeft`:

```
String time = '8:00';
time = time.padLeft(5, '0'); // 08:00
```

The above example adds leading zeros if the length of the string is less than 5.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
 DateTimePickerFormField(
                      lastDate: DateTime.now(),
                      inputType: inputType,
                      format: formats[inputType],
                      editable: editable,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        errorText: _validate ? 'Cannot be left blank':null,
                          labelText: 'Date/Time',
                          hasFloatingPlaceholder: false,
                          filled: true,
                          fillColor: Colors.grey[300]),
                      onFieldSubmitted: (value) {
                        setState(() {
                          _//...........some code
                        });
                      },
                    ),
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem using showTimePicker and *.toString()* didn't work for me either.
I added this function to my class

```
String _addLeadingZeroIfNeeded(int value) {
  if (value < 10) return '0$value';
  return value.toString();
}
```

and since your variable is **picked**, you can use it like this

```
_addLeadingZeroIfNeeded(picked.hour)+':'+_addLeadingZeroIfNeeded(picked.minute)
```

or if you need it as a String, then you can use double quotes and ${}

```
Text("Time: ${_addLeadingZeroIfNeeded(picked.hour)}:${_addLeadingZeroIfNeeded(picked.minute)}")
```

This changes time from 3:5 to 03:05